# Timer in OnStart Method in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have created Windows Service in C# and create system timer and start it in OnStart() method. When I upload service in PC there is a problem. I did debug it so problem is when OnStart method starts timer, all code in any method (DBinsert method) in timer continue infinity ( line 1, line 2,.... line 15 then go to line 1.. again) How can I solve it?

```
Timer tmr = new Timer();

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    tmr.Interval = 5000;
    tmr.Elapsed += tmr_Elapsed;
    tmr.Start();
}

private void tmr_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    DBconnection.DBinsert();
}
```

Comment: It's because your interval is equals to `5` seconds, I guess you are not debugging faster than that.

Comment: Rascar - it's pretty difficult to help with the small about of code you've posted. For example, where is DBconnection initialised? What does DBInsert do? What is the problem you see when you run the service outside of the debugger?

Comment: @DavidKemp All that is irrelevant, OP wants to know, why his code inside `DBinsert()` method executing over and over when he debugging. His `Interval` is set to `5000` milliseconds (which equals to `5` seconds), so if he will start debugging and go through code less than `5` seconds, he will start over and over, because timer has already elapsed.

Comment: With regards to what @SeM has said, perhaps you could add some conditional compilation to the `Elapsed` event handler that will `Stop` the `Timer` when it enters the method and `Start` it again when it leaves.  That way, you can take as long as you like inside that method while debugging and it will not affect your Release build.

Comment: Guys, not only debugging time, It doesn't give result when I just start service without debug... DBinsert is static I don't make instance of  DBconnection class. And in DBinsert I just check outlook mails if new emails exist insert it to database but from some code line it throw 1 line as infinity

Comment: Have you actually timed `DBconnection.DBinsert` to see how long it takes to execute?  Maybe it takes longer than 5 seconds even without debugging.  You can use a `Stopwatch` to time it.

Comment: First, I create copy of all code as C# console application before make service app. All things were ok. Time of execution is not more than 5second. But in windows service it doesn't give any result.

Comment: When I call outlook = new Application() It gives following error
-------------------------------------------------------------
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

Answer (score 1):

I'll post this as an answer so I can post a bit of code.  In case you're not familiar, this is what I meant when I mentioned conditional compilation in my comment:

```
    private void tmr_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
#if DEBUG
        tmr.Stop();
#endif
        DBconnection.DBinsert();
#if DEBUG
        tmr.Start();
#endif
    }
```

Note that that is still going stop and start the `Timer` even if you don't debug that event handler, so it means that your interval will be effectively a bit longer than 5 seconds, but I doubt that that is too big an issue.  You can always set the `Interval` of the `Timer` to a slightly smaller value in Debug to compensate if you need to.